# Error: Offset out of range, in CoIDE

Tags: stm32

I am trying out CooCox CoIDE for developing software to a STM32F100.

When I compile after adding CooCox RTOS (CoOS), I get a error message:

```
   [cc] Starting link
   [cc] arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -g -nostartfiles -flto -Wl,-Map=OS_Test.map -O0 -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--entry=main -LC:\CooCox\CoIDE\configuration\ProgramData\OS_Test -Wl,-TC:\CooCox\CoIDE\configuration\ProgramData\OS_Test/arm-gcc-link.ld -g -o OS_Test.elf ..\obj\kernelHeap.o ..\obj\core.o ..\obj\startup_stm32f10x_md_vl.o ..\obj\core_cm3.o ..\obj\timer.o ..\obj\utility.o ..\obj\system_stm32f10x.o ..\obj\task.o ..\obj\serviceReq.o ..\obj\main.o ..\obj\mbox.o ..\obj\mm.o ..\obj\time.o ..\obj\event.o ..\obj\syscalls.o ..\obj\port.o ..\obj\queue.o ..\obj\mutex.o ..\obj\flag.o ..\obj\arch.o ..\obj\sem.o ..\obj\hook.o
   [cc] C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Temp\cccpkRF6.s: Assembler messages:
   [cc] C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Temp\cccpkRF6.s:240: Error: offset out of range
   [cc] C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Temp\cccpkRF6.s:241: Error: offset out of range
```

I know this isn't much information, but I haven't seen this error before, so i am completely blank, please help :)

EDIT: Oh, and i found out that if I change the optimization from -O0 to -O1 the error becomes:

```
   [cc] ccKXT9LB.s:1163: Error: registers may not be the same -- `strexb r0,r0,[r1]'
   [cc] ccKXT9LB.s:1188: Error: registers may not be the same -- `strexh r0,r0,[r1]'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND IT!

Someone more clever than me can probably explain it, but anyway I got it fixed by unchecking the "Enable LTO" box under linker configuration.

Right click project -> Configuration -> Link tab -> uncheck "Enable LTO". Done..

I hope this will help others.

Answer (score 1):

> Oh, and i found out that if I change the optimization from -O0
>   to -O1 the error becomes:     [cc] ccKXT9LB.s:1163: Error: registers
>   may not be the same -- `strexb r0,r0,[r1]'    [cc] ccKXT9LB.s:1188:
>   Error: registers may not be the same --`strexh r0,r0,[r1]'

Go to cmsis directory of the [firmware](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM147/CL1794/SC961/SS1743/PF257890#), open core_cm3.c and change these functions:

**uint32_t __STREXB(uint8_t value, uint8_t *addr)**

```
uint32_t __STREXB(uint8_t value, uint8_t *addr)
{
   uint32_t result=0;
   __ASM volatile ("strexb %0, %2, [%1]" : "=&r" (result) : "r" (addr), "r" (value));
   return(result);
}
```

**uint32_t __STREXH(uint16_t value, uint16_t *addr)**

```
uint32_t __STREXH(uint16_t value, uint16_t *addr)
{
   uint32_t result=0;
   __ASM volatile ("strexh %0, %2, [%1]" : "=&r" (result) : "r" (addr), "r" (value));
   return(result);
}
```

For the source of the solution see [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-binutils/2011-12/msg00112.html) and [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-binutils/2011-12/msg00122.html)